# Running out of memory while training machine learning model

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn, out-of-memory, random-forest

I have limited memory and training this model is taking too much:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
print("Created Random Forest classifier\n")

data = pd.read_csv("House_2_ALL.csv")
print("Finished reading data\n")

data.drop("UnixTimeStamp",1)
predict = "Aggregate_Power"
print("Dropped UnixTimeStamp\n")

X = np.array(data.drop([predict],1))
Y = np.array(data[predict])
print("Created numpy Arrays\n")

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.1)
print("Assigned Testing/Training Variables\n")

clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Fit model\n")

print("Attempting to predict\n")
print(clf.predict(X_test))
```

When I run this program, my computer states that it has run out of memory and that I need to quit some applications.
Any ideas on how to manage memory better or is the only solution to reduce the size of my training dataset?

I have learned that the program runs smoothly until it gets to the "`clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)`" line so I don't know if this is a problem with pandas' memory hungry datafrmes or sklearn.

Comment: You could do a few things: (1) reduce the size of training set by randomly selecting rows, assuming you have a randomly selected data set, (2) lower the precision of your floating point values (if you have any), trying FP32 or FP16.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the size of your dataset is quite large. You should hence load your dataset in parts for training your model. I will share an example

```
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, chunksize=10000)
# This will load only 10000 rows at a time (you can tune for your RAM)

# Now the df is a generator and hence you can do something like this
for part_df in df:
  '''
  Now here you just consider the "part_df" as your original df and do all
the preprocessing and stuff on it and train the model on it. After training
the model on this part_df you save the model and reload it in the next iteration.
  '''
  df = preprocess_df(df) # Some preprocessing function
  xtrain, xvalid, ytrain, yvalid = train_test_split(df) # Some split
  model = None
  if (os.exists(model_path)): # you won't have a model for first iteration
    model = # Here you load the model
  else:
    model = # Define the model for first iteration of df

  model.fit(...) # train the model

  # Now you save the model for the next iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible scenarios here that could cause `Memory error`.

**1.Pandas.read_csv() with chunk_size**

You could use chunk_size parameters and load the data a smaller chunk at a time(returns an object we can iterate over).

```
chunk_size=50000
reader = pd.read_csv('big_file.csv', chunksize=chunk_size)
for i in range(num):
     data_chunk = next(reader)
     # process chunk
```

**1.Random Forest Classifier/Regressor**

It has default parameters `max_depth=None`,`min_samples_leaf=1` which means full trees are grown. If the dataset is large then the RandomForest could grow fully deep trees and nodes leading to a faster memory consumption.

Let `clf = RandomForestClassifier()`,
`clf.fit(X_train, y_train)`

then you could check on few things like

`print(clf.estimators_[0].tree_.max_depth) # max_depth on a chunk of data.`
`joblib.dump(clf.estimators_[0], "first_tree_clf.joblib") # get the size of a tree.`

Now you can try a definite value for hyperparameter `max_depth` and again fit the model. Tuning of the RandomForest classifier model hyperparameters would create shallow trees per chunk and avoid too much of memory consumption